# Finding app version number in code

Tags: android, version

Is there a simple way to find the current version of my application from within it?  I would like to add the version string to the about screen.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684878/create-manual-versions) question.

I am doing it this way:

```
try {
            String pkg = mContext.getPackageName();
            mVersionNumber = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pkg, 0).versionName;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            mVersionNumber = "?";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

please try out this.

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;
```