# How can I find out if user is using the latest version of application?

Tags: android, release, versioning

I want to remind the user that he is not using the latest release.

How can I get the last version code of my application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881641/finding-app-version-number-in-code

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of it yourself, using SharedPreferences: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

So, from your next version and onwards, the app should store its version number (you can hard code it) in SharedPreferences.

Then request www.yourdomain.com/latest-version-of-my-app, where you return the latest version number of your app. Then compare that with the stored version number value in SharedPreferences and if SharedPreferences value != the response from the URL, then show a dialog prompting for upgrade

Comment: You don't need to have stored a value in sharedpreferences. You could check the appversion at runtime as well. Just fetch it using the correct methods.

Comment: I must have a website... I thought that there was a solution requesting the last version number on market !

Comment: could the market page itself can provide latest version number ?